# Dojo numberspinner for year

Tags: java, javascript, dojo

I am new to DOJO and required to create a Spin-box using DOJO number spinner. The spin box should show value as current year, and the min and max value should be current-year - 100.

Please could someone help me with this.

Comment: It looks like you haven't tried anything yet. I'm afraid no one will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var currentVal = parseInt(dateYear);
var maxVal = current + 100;
var minVal = current - 100;

 var mySpinner = new NumberSpinner({
        value: currentVal,
        constraints: { min:minVal, max:maxVal, places:0 },
        id: "integerspinner3",
        style: "width:100px"
    })
```

Make sure you have all of your requires and place this somewhere.